# How to add row after gridunload/gridReload to a new row?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, row

How to add row after gridunload/gridReload and then appear row with empty data?

Comment: What do you mean under the "row time gridunload"?

Comment: im sorry, i mean add row after gridunload/gridReload.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not understand your requirements. Do you have jqGrid with local or remote data? In general the last event called after every grid loading (or reloading) is `loadComplete`. So you can include any actions like call of `addRowData` inside of `loadComplete`. Nevertheless I don't understand why you could need to do this.

Comment: I mean,i want to create new row after grid automaticly refresh.Can?
Cuz,i need for minimalist my frontend,without button at navigation layer for add row.you can help me for this problem?sorry bother you.=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new empty row in the grid after loading/reloading you can call `addRowData` inside of `loadComplete`. Because we need get an unique id for the new row I suggest to use `$.jgrid.randId()` introduced in 4.0.0 version of jqGrid. So the code can looks like the following

```
$('#list').jqGrid({
    ...
    loadComplete: function() {
        // we can include some default value
        // in the case the value will be { colName: "my default value" }
        var newRowData = {},
            newRowId = $.jgrid.randId(),
            myGrid = $(this);

        myGrid.jqGrid('addRowData', newRowId, newRowData);
        myGrid.jqGrid('setSelection', newRowId);  // select new row
        myGrid.jqGrid('editRow', newRowId, true); // editing the row
    }
});
```

In the above example I selected additionally new added row and then started the editing of the row with respect of inline editing. There lines are just examples for some actions which you can additionally do with the new empty row.

Comment: oleg?
i current cant ask question on stack overflow.i dont know why, but i very need help in my problem.=(

Comment: @soccerenz: You wrote, that you has a problem, but not wrote which one you have. Try to place your question now or try to describe the problem in the comment at least.

Comment: Yesterday I could not ask in this forum, but now i can.Thanks =)

Comment: excuse me, sorry mr.oleg
iam have question, why now I can not ask questions on Stact Overflow?
When i need help with my problem.=(

Comment: @soccerenz: Sorry, I have no idea. Probably someone from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ can help you. Are you sure that you login on the stackoverflow before asking the question? It could be some technical problems on the stackoverflow. You can just try to ask the question now.

Comment: i dont know, but already try for ask the question and can not again.
his ask "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."
Ok,how i can found way for create search column in jqgrid?Do you know?